# how can I prevent this perl one-liner from deleting the line containing 'm_nMaxParticles'?

Tags: perl

how can I prevent this perl one-liner from deleting the line containing `m_nMaxParticles`? Just add text after it starting with `m_ConstantColor` and leaving the line containing 'm_nMaxParticles' intact.

```
perl -i -pe "s/(m_nMaxParticles.*)/\n\tm_ConstantColor = \n\t[\n\t\t0,\n\t\t230,\n\t\t255,\n\t\t255,\n\t]\n\tm_nConstantSequenceNumber = 6/g" "C:\MyFile.vpcf"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That regex matches a pattern in the first part and then *replaces it* by what is worked out in the second part.  One way to retain what is matched is to *capture it* so to be able to restore it, by including it in the replacement.

The code does capture its match by `()`, which stores it in `$1`; so add `$1` to the beginning of your replacement string (`s/.../$1\n\tm_ConstantColor.../`).

Or, you can instruct the engine to drop/"forget" what it matched, so that it stays in the string and it need not be put back into it.  This is done with the handy [\K](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#%5CK), which is a [lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), which makes it discard all matches up to that point (to the left of it)

```
perl -i -pe "s/m_nMaxParticles.*\K/\n\tm_ConstantColor = \n\t[\n\t\t0,\n\t\t230,\n\t\t255,\n\t\t255,\n\t]\n\tm_nConstantSequenceNumber = 6/g" "C:\MyFile.vpcf"
```

Now we don't need to capture anything so I removed `()`.  The rest -- replacement -- is the same.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean ;)

Comment: @LGZana  That `\K` is super handy. It's a clean way to match things but not have them removed, what `s///` operator normally does.  (Or of course nothing's wrong with using the capture you have, with `$1`)

Comment: \K is very cool [Ignore part of a substitution’s match](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2012/10/ignore-part-of-a-substitutions-match/)